# Problem with using spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.add() method

Tags: spacy, matcher

I am getting an error when trying to use spacy `matcher`:

```
~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\matcher\matcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.add()
TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)
```

Is there any alternate function for `spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.add()`?

Answer (score 10):

See the [SpaCy `Matcher.add()` documentation](https://spacy.io/api/matcher#add):

> **Changed in v3.0**
> As of spaCy v3.0, `Matcher.add` takes a list of patterns as the second argument (instead of a variable number of arguments). The `on_match` callback becomes an optional keyword argument.
>
> `patterns = [[{"TEXT": "Google"}, {"TEXT": "Now"}], [{"TEXT": "GoogleNow"}]]`
> `- matcher.add("GoogleNow", on_match, *patterns)`
> `+ matcher.add("GoogleNow", patterns, on_match=on_match)`

Example usage:

```py
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
pattern = [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}]
matcher.add("HelloWorld", [pattern])
doc = nlp("hello world!")
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `matcher.add('Relation_name', None, pattern)`

You can use: `matcher.add('Relation_name', [pattern], on_match=None)`

Comment: this work for latest version of spacy, Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3):

In addition, if you have multiple patterns to be extracted, an example would be as below.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

from spacy.matcher import Matcher
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)

pattern1 = [{'LOWER':'solarpower'}]
pattern2 = [{'LOWER':'solar'},{'IS_PUNCT':True},{'LOWER':'power'}]
pattern3 = [{'LOWER':'solar'},{'LOWER':'power'}]

matcher.add('SolarPower', [pattern1,pattern2,pattern3])
doc = nlp(u"The Solar Power industry continues to grow a solarpower increases. Solar-power is good")
found_matches = matcher(doc)


for _,start,end in found_matches:
    span = doc[start:end]
    print(span)
```

##### Output would be:

```
Solar Power 
solarpower 
Solar-power
```

---

Answer (score 0):

The Error message clearly says that you should have only 2 arguments, So just

```
matcher.add("xxxxxxx", ['pattern1', 'pattern2'])
```

**NOTE:**
***pattern should be a list or it will throw error***

Answer (score -1):

The pattern should be surrounded by 2 outside square brackets to work (bold for clarification).  It then works and finds pattern in text

pattern = **[**[{"TEXT": "iPhone"}, {"TEXT": "X"}]**]**

## Add the pattern to the matcher

matcher.add("IPHONE_X_PATTERN", pattern)