# TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Why I am getting this error Can anyone tell please
or explain me how to use it using simple example

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_33/3577035061.py in <module>
      6 # Matcher class object
      7 matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
----> 8 matcher.add("matching_1", None, pattern)
      9 
     10 matches = matcher(doc)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/matcher/matcher.pyx in spacy.matcher.matcher.Matcher.add()

TypeError: add() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (3 given)
```

[image]

In Below link
https://spacy.io/api/matcher
[image]

Comment: As covered in the docs you screenshotted, you are using the v2 calling style, but that API changed in spaCy v3. ljdyer's answer is right.

Answer (score 9):

The new version of spacy [needs square brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66164156/problem-with-using-spacy-matcher-matcher-matcher-add-method) around pattern. Also, callback became an optional term.

Therefore in your case you just need:

```
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("matching_1", [pattern])
matches = matcher(doc)
```

Answer (score 3):

What are you passing the `None` for? It looks like you just need:

```
matcher.add("matching_1", pattern)
```

You are getting the error because the function takes 2 unnamed arguments but you are trying to pass 3. If you want to pass a callback function as well you would need to write:

```
matcher.add("matching_1", pattern, on_match = my_callback_function)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
If you anyother answer feel free to answer

```
# load spaCy model
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text = "GDP in developing countries such as Vietnam will continue growing at a high rate." 

# create a spaCy object 
doc = nlp(text)

#define the pattern 
pattern = [[{'POS':'NOUN'}, 
           {'LOWER': 'such'}, 
           {'LOWER': 'as'}, 
           {'POS': 'PROPN'}] ]#proper noun
# Matcher class object 
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab) 
matcher.add("matching_1",patterns=pattern) 

matches = matcher(doc) 
span = doc[matches[0][1]:matches[0][2]] 

print(span.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
matcher.add("matching_1", [pattern])
```

This worked for me

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).